# Spbayes package-spLM function-Error in spRecover( , c++ error: dpotrf failed

Tags: r, geospatial, bayesian

I'm having an issue with spRecover in the spBayes package. spLM runs perfectly fine. SpRecover runs for exponential and spherical models, however I get the "c++ error: dpotrf failed" error in the gaussian case. I do not have duplicate coordinates. Does anyone know how to proceed?

I have tried adjusting the rounding of coordinates to eliminate all duplicates and adding jitter, however I am still having the same issue.

```
sp <- spLM(daily_data ~ data.type, data = data_tot,coords=coords,starting=list("phi"= 0.7249594 ,"sigma.sq"=30.88157, "tau.sq"= 7.122322), tuning=list("phi"=0.1,"sigma.sq"=0.05, "tau.sq"=0.05), priors=list("phi.Unif"=c(((0.7249594)/7.5),(9)), "sigma.sq.IG"=c((23.75925),(30.88157)), "tau.sq.IG"=c((23.75925),7.122322)), cov.model="gaussian",n.samples=n.samples) round(summary(mcmc(sp$p.theta.samples))$quantiles,3) 

#composition sampling to get posterior samples of marginalized regression coefficients and the spatial effects 
burn.in <- floor(0.75*n.samples) 
fin.sp <- spRecover(sp, start=burn.in)
```